# How can I mark a type or member obsolete in an assembly that I do not control?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, visual-studio, obsolete

Example: My colleagues are supposed not to use `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection` anymore, and I'd like the build process to should point them to the replacement type. This sounds like a case for the `ObsoleteAttribute`, except that I can't set attributes in `Microsoft.VisualBasic.Collection`. Is there a way to achieve something like this (obsoleting/banning a framework type or member for some piece of project) without resorting to ugly hacks.

If not, what are the hacks?

Update: Visual Studio 2017 CE

Comment: Have a look at code analyzers: https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/wiki/How-To-Write-a-C%23-Analyzer-and-Code-Fix

Comment: Yep, I've seen them. But it looks like a lot of work for something that's already there (depreciating a type).

Comment: ...but AFAIK that's the way to do it without hacking the framework-assembly as you can't "externally add attributes". A "wrapper type" to just add the attribute also does not help in your case as your colleagues would just not use the wrapper type. And you should be able to use most of the boiler-plate code from the link above and only implement the actual "type check and warning", which should keep the amount of work to a minimum. See it as a nice coding exercise to learn something new ;-)... (and share a working solution with us, if you implement it)

Comment: You can also use the Code Analysis tools that have replaced FxCop: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/visualstudio/code-quality/code-analysis-for-managed-code-overview

Comment: "I'd like the build process to should point them to the replacement type." - Is this an absolute requirement?  If not, I can post a _hack_ solution to make the build fail.

Answer (score 1):

For the folks coming to this question in 2023 and later, there is now a Roslyn analyzer for that.

See [Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn-analyzers/blob/main/src/Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers/BannedApiAnalyzers.Help.md).

You need to:

1. Reference the analyzer package (using a `Directory.Build.props` or a custom `props` file will allow doing that globally for a solution);

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.CodeAnalysis.BannedApiAnalyzers" Version="3.3.4">
           <PrivateAssets>all</PrivateAssets>
           <IncludeAssets>runtime; build; native; contentfiles; analyzers</IncludeAssets>
       </PackageReference>
   </ItemGroup>
   ```
2. Create a new `BannedSymbols.txt` and include all the banned symbols into it;
3. Include `BannedSymbols.txt` into the same projects as the analyzer;

   ```
   <ItemGroup>
       <AdditionalFiles Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)/BannedSymbols.txt" />
   </ItemGroup>
   ```

E.g. in order to ban `Refit.RestService` type, you'll need to have sth like `T:Refit.RestService;Don't use it`, which will result in a compilation warning in both your IDE, dotnet CLI and CI.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This is not a case for `ObsoleteAttribute` - as that would imply that Microsoft intend to remove this class.

As @ChrFin suggests, the solution is to use an Analyzer (aka a linter) to enforce coding standards, rather than try and hack code you don't own.